# Render a Three.Js scene to an animated GIF file with custom intervals

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, webgl, gif

I am trying to render an animated Three.js scene (basically a dynamic mesh loader that rotates the object 360 degrees automatically) to a GIF file.
Basically I would like the GIF to contain frames that would be "screenshoted" from the WebGL canvas every x seconds/ms.

I have been searching for a few hours but I didn't find any good ressources on this subject.

Thanks.

Comment: it is not for gif but you can still add it on a web page. take a look at http://antimatter15.com/wp/2012/08/whammy-a-real-time-javascript-webm-encoder/

Answer (score 16):

Some years ago I did exactly that. You can have a look at the code here:

https://mrdoob.github.io/omggif-example/

Comment: Thank you very much, it looks exactly like what I need! Do you have any idea if it would work on a server-side setting?
What would be the way to go in this case if my server side is Python-Django based?

Thank you so much!!

Comment: Link is dead. Do you still have this code? Or an alternative?

Comment: Fixed dead link.

Answer (score 4):

I've just found this repository [that](https://github.com/hughsk/gl-gif) seems the right one!

> Quickly and easily generate looping GIFs using WebGL

Or maybe have a look at [this](https://github.com/spite/ccapture.js):

> A library to capture canvas-based animations